Using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with Apple USB Keyboard the changes to the layout are not pemament
Recently, I switched to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS running on my late 2025 iMac. Sadly, the Macintosh keyboard layout doesn't work as expected on my USB-connected Apple A1243 USB keyboard.
For switching the function of the left CMD and crtl I use the following command

setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl

To properly use my fn keys, I use

sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"

Followed by

sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

Sadly, every time I reboot, the changes are gone. I get it for switching CMD and crtl, but not for the fnmode. How can I make the changes permanent? On my 2012 MacBook pro running Zorin OS, this is working out of the box.
EDiT:
It worked with the following script:
#!/bin/bash 
# Swap left CMD and CTRL keys 
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl 
# Set fn mode echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode' 

After making it executable with
chmod +x ~/set_keyboard.sh

I added it to Startup applications with this command:
/bin/bash -c "~/set_keyboard.sh"

Also, added it to the sudoers file using visudo to enable sudo without password for this specific command:
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode



One way would be to put it in a script (test the scriipt) and add it to startup applications.

Ah, great idea! It worked with the following script:
'#!/bin/bash
Swap left CMD and CTRL keys
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl
Set fn mode
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode'
After making it executable, I added it to Startup applications with this command:
'/bin/bash -c "~/set_keyboard.sh"'
Also, added it to the sudoers file using visudo to enable sudo without password for this specific command.

great, now write an answer out of what you did :)

Ok, i edited my initial post with the steps i took to solve it :)

No I meant an answer, answer your question you can do it:)

ah, understood. Sorry, I am new to this platform :)

Read Help in the bottom of screen, and do not forget to accept ypur answer after a while when it becomes available.

It worked with the following script:
#!/bin/bash 
# Swap left CMD and CTRL keys 
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl 
# Set fn mode 
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode 

After making it executable with
chmod +x ~/set_keyboard.sh

I added it to Startup applications with this command:
/bin/bash -c "~/set_keyboard.sh"

Also, added it to the sudoers file using visudo to enable sudo without password for this specific command:
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode

